# Parse JSON Object in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a set of json objects I want to read that data using a spark scala I will put a sample file data below one file contains more than 100 objects.

//file1

```
{
  "id":"31342547689",
  "Name":"Jacob",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Accounts"
}
{
  "id":"987875637898",
  "Name":"Martin",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Sr.Accounts"
}
{
  "id":"64542457879",
  "Name":"lucifer",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Developer"
}
{
  "id":"23824723354",
  "Name":"Ratin",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Sr.Developer"
}
```

when I used the below code I can able to print only the first object.

```
val dataframe = spark
      .read
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .schema(Schema)
      .json("D:\\appdata\file1")
      .show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your file doesn't have a valid Json. You can also validate it at https://jsonlint.com/ .
Ideally, it should be like this

```
[{
  "id":"31342547689",
  "Name":"Jacob",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Accounts"
},
{
  "id":"987875637898",
  "Name":"Martin",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Sr.Accounts"
},
{
  "id":"64542457879",
  "Name":"lucifer",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Developer"
},
{
  "id":"23824723354",
  "Name":"Ratin",
  "Sex":"M",
  "Destination":"Sr.Developer"
}]
```

So, first we need to preprocess this file to turn it into a valid Json.

```
val df=sc.wholeTextFiles("/yourHDFSLocation/file1.json").toDF
df.select("_2").map(s=>"["+s.mkString.replaceAll("\\}.*\n{0,}.*\\{","},{")+"]").repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").text("/yourHDFSLocation/correctedJson/")
```

Then we can read our valid json.

```
val ok=spark.read.schema(simpleSchema).option("multiline", "true").json("/yourHDFSLocation/correctedJson/p*")
```

Ouput:

```
ok.show(false)
+------------+-------+---+------------+
|id          |Name   |Sex|Destination |
+------------+-------+---+------------+
|31342547689 |Jacob  |M  |Accounts    |
|987875637898|Martin |M  |Sr.Accounts |
|64542457879 |lucifer|M  |Developer   |
|23824723354 |Ratin  |M  |Sr.Developer|
+------------+-------+---+------------+
```

Another solution, if you don't want to save an intermediate file.

```
val rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles("/yourHDFSLocation/file1.json")
val rdd2=rdd.map(s=>"["+s._2.replaceAll("\\}.*\n{0,}.*\\{","},{")+"]")
val ok=spark.read.schema(simpleSchema).option("multiline", "true").json(rdd2)
```

Hope it resolves this problem!

Comment: value wholeTextFiles is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext I am facing this sc.wholeTextFiles

Comment: Input JSON file is perfectly fine  .. it is not needed to be present as an array of objects.   it is not mandatory to clean the input file.

Comment: Please try this spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles

Comment: yea but I don't want to write in any location on the fly I want to read it

Comment: @DuskyDood i have updated my answer in which you don't need to save an intermediate file.

Comment: thanks, man it worked like a charm. one more doubt if I want to pass two different files and schema what I have to do without creating another set of above code?

Comment: welcome! if you have two files and same schema, then place these file under same directory and  read it using only directory path e.g 
val rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles("/yourHDFSLocationwithTwoFiles/")
But if schema is different then you have to do the whole thing twice

Comment: then it needs to be done twice as both are different datasets

Comment: @viapak can we read data without wholeTextFile? or using any other option

Answer (score 1):

you can read the pretty jsons file by using spark **wholeTextFiles** API

```
import spark.implicits._
val input = spark.wholeTextFiles(inputFile).map(_._2)

val ouput = input.mapPartitions(records => {
    // mapper object created on each executor node (ObjectMapper is not serializable so we either create a singleton object for each partition)
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
     records.map(eachitem => {
        try {
            mapper.readValue(record, classOf[DTOclass])
         }catch {
           case e: Exception => null
         }
     })
   }).filter(_!=null).toDF.as[DTOclass]
ouput.write.json(oplocation)
```

you can use the Gson library as well instead of ObjectMapper.

**note : DTOclass should be serializable**

or you can clean your input pretty jsons file and can read it by `spark.read.json` API as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453769/reading-pretty-print-json-files-in-apache-spark).