# Apache spark parsing json with splitted records

Tags: json, apache-spark

As far as I know, Apache spark requires json file to have one record in exactly one string. I have a splitted by fields json file like this:

```
{"id": 123,
"name": "Aaron",
"city": {
    "id" : 1,
    "title": "Berlin"
}}
{"id": 125,
"name": "Bernard",
"city": {
    "id" : 2,
    "title": "Paris"
}}
{...many more lines
...}
```

How can I parse it using Spark? Do I need a preprocessor or can I provide custom splitter?

Comment: What is the Spark version you are using ?

Comment: @mrsrinivas 1.6.2. Does it matter?

Comment: Not sure. But thought of adding answer according to Spark version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark uses splitting by newline to distinguish records. This mean that when using the standard json reader you would need to have one record per line.

You can convert by doing something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30452120/1547734

The basic idea would be to read as a wholeTextFiles and then load it to a json reader which would parse it and flatmap the results.

Of course this assumes the files are big enough to be in memory and parsed one at a time. Otherwise you would need more complicated solutions.

Comment: so if my file is big enough to not fit in RAM, it is not an option?

Comment: no. The only way I can think of then is to do it manually. If you have one such file, create a program that reads it one line at a time until it reconstructs the record and then write it as a single line to an output (i.e. preprocess).

Comment: Yes, I supposed it is the only way before asking the question. Thank you!